# Cache system in Scala

Tags: scala

I´m looking to implement a Cache solution in Scala to cache some Finagle services that I want to avoid create per request if the host and path are alike.

I've read several solutions, Guava, Memo patter of Scalaz, or even using Map. 
Could you please give me any recommendation?

Regards

Comment: https://github.com/cb372/scalacache would be a good choice. Depends what is your actual requirement. Please provide more technical details what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava Cache is an excellent library for this, and it is stable and high quality.

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained